# Removal of cut edge disconnects this graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am not sure how does removing cut edge {a,b} disconnects the graph. My interpretation of disconnect means when the graph has multiple components.

Original graph before removal

[image]

graph after removal-how is this a graph that is disconnected? It should not be disconnected, correct?

[image]

Comment: Don't remove the point $a$, just the edge between $a$ and $b$. Then what remains is pretty clearly disconnected, right?

Comment: Oh I get it now! Gracias! + 1 to both!

Answer (score 3):

Removing an edge means deleting *only* the edge, and not the vertices incident to it. In your example, the vertex $a$ remains as an isolated vertex and isolated vertices are certainly connected components.

Comment: Understood the edge and not the vertices incident with the edge. Much clearer. +1.